# How do I prevent a phonegap app from navigating away from it's local files?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cordova, social-networking

I have a PhoneGap application with an iFrame which is loading content from a site I control. (same domain as the app)

The problem is that when using Javascript widgets like Facebook and Twitter, it's possible to navigate away from the local top level frame. I wouldn't mind so much if it were just the iFrame, but it's eating the whole app, and my preference really is to just redirect the user to an external browser to show the site.

How does one prevent this?

I've tried to counter with modification to the webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: method, but that won't work on other platforms, and I cannot easily distinguish between external resources loading in iFrames (SNS widgets) and the same scripts replacing the top level frame.

Answer (score 0):

I think ChildBrowser Plugin can work for you. It will not redirect the calls to webbrowser but I believe it will satisfy your needs. It supports [iOS](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser) and [Android](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser).

> The child browser allows you to display external webpages within your
>   PhoneGap/Cordova application.
>
> A simple use case would be:
>
> - Users can follow links/buttons to view web content without leaving
>     your app.
> - Display web pages/images/videos/pdfs in the ChildBrowser.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I want.  Most of the content of the app is from a web site, and I want to display that inline below a toolbar.  At the moment, I've taken to intercepting the external URL requests, and translating them into platform specific API requests.  Not ideal, and it rather defeats the platform independence of Cordova, but it works.